Letter case error prompts appear repeatedly during crosstool-ng build, and an error occurs in CT_Abort
    [INFO ]  Performing some trivial sanity checks
    [ERROR]  Your file system in '/mnt/c/Users/yux/denoise/arm-linux-tools/x-tools/arm-unknown-linux- gnueabi' is *not* case-sensitive!
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR]  >>
    [ERROR]  >>  Build failed in step '(top-level)'
    [ERROR]  >>
    [ERROR]  >>  Error happened in: CT_Abort[scripts/functions@488]
    [ERROR]  >>        called from: CT_TestAndAbort[scripts/functions@508]
    [ERROR]  >>        called from: main[scripts/crosstool-NG.sh@122]
    [ERROR]  >>
    [ERROR]  >>  For more info on this error, look at the file: 'build.log'
    [ERROR]  >>  There is a list of known issues, some with workarounds, in:
    [ERROR]  >>      https://crosstool-ng.github.io/docs/known-issues/
    [ERROR]  >>
    [ERROR]  >>  If you feel this is a bug in crosstool-NG, report it at:
    [ERROR]  >>      https://github.com/crosstool-ng/crosstool-ng/issues/
    [ERROR]  >>
    [ERROR]  >>  Make sure your report includes all the information pertinent to this issue.
    [ERROR]  >>  Read the bug reporting guidelines here:
    [ERROR]  >>      http://crosstool-ng.github.io/support/
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR]  (elapsed: 28547130:42.16)
    [00:01] / make: *** [/usr/local/bin/ct-ng:261: build] Error 1


I have tried reconfiguring the menuconfig download package path and program storage path, and also used emacs to modify the path information. and other related options. I used crosstool-ng-1.26.0.tar.bz2 to install it. I didn’t use git clone because it couldn’t be installed because there was no corresponding makefile.in in it. I don’t know which step caused the problem
